# Ansible: "URL can't contain control characters"

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ansible

I'm trying to install kubectl in my localhost using ansible, but i get the  below error message:

> > fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "dest": "/temp/", "msg": "An unknown error occurred: URL can't contain control characters. '/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl' (found at least ' ')", "state": "absent", "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"}

I believe the issue might be with the back-tick characters in the url. I have tried surrounding them with single quotes and backslashes, but they didn't work. 
Here is my playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: install kubectl
      get_url:
        url: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/`curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt`/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
        dest: /usr/local/bin/
        mode: '0440'
```

Comment: you are right, the `curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt` is not allowed there - your syntax is for a shell script, ansible cant work with that. you need to get it to a variable with another task, register it to a variable and use that variable in the posted task, using `{{ }}`.

Comment: vars:
   url_path: "curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt"
 url: https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/{{url_path}}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl. I just tried it didn't work. I tried to use shell, but i got the warning to use get_url or uri module.

Comment: I went ahead and used a specific version "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.17.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" instead. According to the doc, the one with the back-stick would give me a stable version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the result of curl into variable using 'shell' module, and reference it in the 'get_url' module:

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: get version
      shell: curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt
      register: version
    - name: install kubectl
      get_url:
        url: "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/{{ version.stdout }}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
        dest: /usr/local/bin/
        mode: '0440'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an alterative, you can also use the URI builtin module

```
- name: Check whether kubectl is installed
  stat:
    path: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
  register: kubectl_exists

- name: Search for latest kubectl release
  uri:
    url: https://cdn.dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt
    return_content: true
  register: kubectl_ver_response
  when: not kubectl_exists.stat.exists

- name: Download/Install kubectl
  get_url:
    url: "https://dl.k8s.io/release/{{ kubectl_ver_response.content }}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
    dest: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    mode: 0755
    group: root
    owner: root
  when: not kubectl_exists.stat.exists
```